# CME Metals Settlement methodology

Tags: futures, forward, cme, settlement, forward-curve

I'm reading the docs on CME Metal's settlement methodology and looking at the examples section: https://www.cmegroup.com/confluence/display/EPICSANDBOX/Metals+Futures+Settlement+Algorithm+Examples

For the April contract, since no spreads traded during the 13:15-13:30 settlement window, they calculate an implied bid/ask *using all of the calendar spread markets where the April was the deferred leg*. Does this mean all spreads traded during the standard market session for this day? I don't understand what **all** means and how far it reaches.

Also, for the December (deferred) contract, they only use spreads Aug-Dec, June-Dec and Dec-Dec(deferred). What about Feb-Dec, Apr-Dec? Were they simply not traded during the window?

Comment: They try to use **trades**, but if there are no trades during 13:15-13:30 window, then they use **bid/asks** (presumably as of 13:30) in those spread markets where April is the deferred month, and form a single bid ask from those. They **don't** look at trades before 13:15 for the same day.

Comment: (another term for bid/asks is **quotes**)